# Dividir String em blocos, considerando apenas letras ou texto entre colchetes

Tags: java, string, regex

Se eu tiver uma String assim:

```
"Olá, o meu nome é [José Cavalo]"
```

E eu der split:

```
{"Olá,", "o", "meu", "nome", "é", "[José", "Cavalo]"}
```

Primeiramente, temos um problema. No índice 0, temos `"Olá,"`, e queremos separar o `"Olá"` da vírgula. Depois, eu queria separar a `String` em blocos, detetando os parênteses retos, e juntando `"José"` com `"Cavalo"`, ficando `"[José Cavalo]"`, num só elemento (bloco, como explicitado no título)

Eu pensei em usar regex para o caso do bloco:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^)]+)\\]").matcher("Olá, o meu nome é [José Cavalo]");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Mas o comportamento deste pedaço de código não é o esperado. Se tivermos múltiplos blocos, ele apenas faz o primeiro parêntese reto com o último parêntese reto de todos:

```
//Consideremos a seguinte String:
String s = "[bloco1] [bloco2]";
//... Aqui vai o código do regex para a separacao ...

//Resultado:
//bloco1] [bloco2
```

Temos já aqui dois problemas:

O primeiro é o tal problema de "primeiro parêntese reto > último parêntese reto de todos".
O segundo é que ele **remove** os parênteses retos. Eu não quero isso, pois já tenho uma função separada para os remover.

Não faço ideia nenhuma de como separar a vírgula do `"Olá"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua regex você usou `[^)]`, que é "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `)`". E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, por padrão, é ["ganancioso"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tenta pegar o máximo de caracteres possível (por isso no caso de ter `"[bloco1] [bloco2]"`, ele pega a string toda, já que você só disse que não podia pegar `)`, então a regex pode pegar `[` ou `]` a mais, caso ache necessário - e o comportamento "ganancioso" diz que é para pegar).

Se não quer que pegue os colchetes, inclua-os na classe de caracteres (lembrando de escapá-los com `\`):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]")
                   .matcher("Olá, o meu nome é [José Cavalo] [bloco 1] [bloco 2]");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

A saída é:

```
José Cavalo
bloco 1
bloco 2
```

Se quer que o resultado seja `[José Cavalo]`, `[bloco 1]` e `[bloco 2]` (com os colchetes), basta trocar o `m.group(1)` para `m.group(0)` (ou apenas `m.group()`, sem parâmetros - ambos pegam todo o *match* encontrado).

Você também poderia usar `"\\[([^\\[\\]()]+)\\]"` (incluir o `(` e `)` na classe de caracteres), assim a regex não pega colchetes nem parênteses.

---

Agora para pegar somente `Olá` (sem a vírgula) você pode usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`:

```
String s = "Olá, o meu nome é [José Cavalo]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Também usei a opção [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) para considerar caracteres acentuados.

E para pegar tanto a palavra sem a vírgula, quanto o caso dos colchetes, use [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"):

```
String s = "Olá, o meu nome é [José Cavalo] [bloco 1] [bloco 2]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]|\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Assim, a regex tenta primeiro pegar caracteres entre colchetes. Se não conseguir, ela tenta pegar a sequência de `\w`.

A saída é:

```
Olá
o
meu
nome
é
[José Cavalo]
[bloco 1]
[bloco 2]
```

---

Um detalhe é que `\w` também considera números e o caractere `_`. Se quiser limitar a somente letras, outra opção é usar as [*Unicode Properties*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/):

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]|\\p{L}+").matcher(s);
```

No caso, `\p{L}` pega todas as letras definidas pelo Unicode (são todas as categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Só que isso inclui outros alfabetos, como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc. Se quiser se limitar a apenas ao nosso alfabeto, outra opção é usar `\p{Script=Latin}`:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]|\\p{Script=Latin}+").matcher(s);
```

Em ambos os casos, não precisa usar a opção `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`.